# Sql Server 2005 enterprise on Windows 7

Tags: windows, sql-server-2005, windows-7

Is there any possibility to install Sql Server 2005 enterprise on Windows 7?

thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep, works fine.

Make sure that you install it before Visual Studio, and also make sure you enable these Windows features first:

**Common HTTP Features**

- Static Content
- Default Document
- HTTP Redirection
- Directory Browsing

**Application Development**

- ASP.Net
- ISAPI Extension
- ISAPI Filters

**Security**

- Windows Authentication

**IIS6**

- IIS 6 WMI
- IIS Metabase

Then install SP2 at least, but preferably SP3

Comment: we're talking about enterprise version of sql server 2005, right?

Comment: Worked for me with Win7 + SQL2005 Standard.

Comment: worked for me with win7 (ultimate) + sql developer edition. Didnt try with enterprise version sorry.

Comment: Enterprise edition cannot be installed on client OS. It works on server OS.

Answer (score 5):

SQL Server 2005 Enterprise Edition is not supported on client OS's like Vista, XP, or Windows 7.  Developer Edition is supported on the client OS's and allow you to develop with Enterprise features, but Enterprise Edition is only supported on Window Server Installations as per the BOL:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506(SQL.90).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible:

1. http://blogs.msdn.com/sqlexpress/archive/2009/05/14/installing-sql-server-express-on-windows-7-release-candidate.aspx
2. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssetup/thread/6a569376-4207-4184-a8a7-73d5168c787e

You'll need to use Service Pack 3

Comment: Please note that I'm asking for enterprise version of sql server 2005, not express edition or sql server 2008!

Anyway thanks for try

Comment: I would be surprised if Express was supported and Enterprise wasn't.

Comment: What's the issue? You getting an eror or something?

Answer (score 0):

Enterprise edition does work only on Server OSs (Server 2k3 2k8 ...) if you are just using it for development try Sql server developer edition it has the same features as Enterprise and it is way cheaper (But it can be used for development only).